# Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing not Calculating Correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this plugin installed on my main website and it's not discounting the product based on the rules I've set up.

0 items up to 999 items are .69/pc

1000 items up are .67/pc.

I then installed WP on a dev site I don't use then installed woocommerce and the woocomerce dynamic pricing plugin. It doesn't calculate right  on this site either.

Example: http://dev.healthproductscenter.com/?product=test

The pricing get's marked down, as you can see in the above example ( add 1000 to the cart and it shows it's .67), but the total is not the discounted rate. It's the original rate of .69

I have no other plugins installed except what I mentioned.

I've got to be missing something but can't find it.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's a global bug. Take a look at these comments https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279/comments

Comment: If you have the official Dynamic Pricing plugin from WooCommerce you should contact them for support.

Comment: The screenshot looks like not a screenshot from a Dynamic Pricing page

Answer (score 0):

We had this exact problem on staging it was one of the debugging tools we were running on staging. As such the problem didn't occur in production were to debugging tool was not active.